# WiX Toolset: Creating a Simple Setup

Tags: wix

Does this simple walkthrough work for anyone else? Doesn't for me. Error: The ComponentGroup element contains an unexpected child element 'File'. Is this walkthrough out of date, invalid or am I possibly just doing something stupid? The version of WiX I have installed is 3.10. and Visual Studio 2015. Thanks

[Creating a Simple Setup](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/votive/authoring_first_votive_project.html)

Comment: Tip: The schema help would tell you the possible children of [ComponentGroup](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/xsd/wix/componentgroup.html) and conversely the possible parents of [File](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/xsd/wix/file.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you missed the creating the component tag. The File tag can only be added underneath the Component tag. Think of Components as containers for anything that gets deployed.

```
<Component Id="ProductComponent">
                <!-- TODO: Insert files, registry keys, and other resources here. -->
            </Component>
```

Comment: Note: [In general, you should restrict yourself to a single file per component.](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/howtos/files_and_registry/add_a_file.html) Also see [Organizing Applications into Components](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa370561(v=vs.85).aspx).

Comment: @Isaish4110 Wow, that list of plurals in your TODO makes me uncomfortable.

Comment: @Tom- :) That's copied as-is from the default VS 2013 setup project, and I agree with you it's better to keep a single file per component.

Comment: The sample supplied by WiX didn't specify and in my ignorance I didn't add it. Once I did however, then all is well. Thank you.